# Magento 2.2.3 Top category menu suddenly disappeared

Tags: magento, menu, navigation, categories

Sorry in advance I'm not very familiar with Magento.

**I am working on a Magento Web Shop and one day the top navigation, where you can open the categories, just disappeared. I tried searching in the vendor folder for the Block or templates for it but no success there. Didn't find a solution in the Admin panel as well. Searched in Google, but the only thing I found was about Varnish, which I'm not using.**

**I'm open to any suggestions and questions.**

Comment: provide me the url of the site

Answer (score 0):

Look in Vendor/magento/module_theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
remove ttl="3600" from

This happens on sites without ssl (local?)
Preferably you make a child theme first and put the catalog.topnav section in the default.xml of your theme otherwise you have to repeat this with every update..